# What is the screen that appears after the hero selection with coloured bars and numbers?

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

In Heroes of Newerth, when you join a game, after you and all others have selected the heroes, there is a count down, after that a screen appears showing all player names on either side of the screen, but with coloured bars moving slowly towards the middle. As the colored bars reach the middle as single digit number appears on them. After all bars reaches the middle, the game suddenly starts. What is the meaning of this screen with bars and numbers and no explanatory text what so ever. No info available on google or in any of the game's guides I have seen.

An image of similar screen can be seen here: http://michaelurvan.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/ebc5d763afba23dbd6611acee5abc92d.png
I say similar because, unlike in the image, I see two sets of coloured bars in my PC, one for each team.

Comment: Dosent look like that with its differing speeds of moving, and colour codes and numbers that appear on them.

Comment: You can see an image of it, I found in google http://michaelurvan.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/ebc5d763afba23dbd6611acee5abc92d.png

Comment: From the screenshot, that is a loading screen. Moving at different speeds would match people computer being different. The number seems to indicate which player was done loading 1st, 2nd, etc.

Comment: I dont know how knowing who has finished loading 1st, 2nd et all will help,since game wont start untill all has loaded, unless there is some game mechanic associated with it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau If I may ask have you actually seen the screen in action while playing HON?

Comment: Never played HoN, so that's why I'm commenting rather than answering and why this one will be my last.

Answer (score 2):

That is simply the game loading screen. The bars move at different speeds as different people's computer/internet connection allow them to load at different rates. The number you see indicates what order people finished loading in. As you noted in your comment this has no affect on actual game play, other than perhaps allowing you to see who is playing on a poor computer (long load time) and thus might have slower reactions in game.